# How can I create a Google Spreadsheets whose name and cells auto-complete with cells completed on another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, automation, project-management

I'm using **Google Spreadsheets** to manage projects, and I'm not familiar with scripts or macros.

#### What is:

1) I have a *Gantt spreadsheet* which lists all the ongoing and foreseen project as follows (by column): name of the project, person in charge, beginning and end date (among others columns).

2) Each line corresponds to a specific project, which has its own spreadsheet (which I have to complete again with the information of the *Gantt spreadsheet*). The URL of each spreadsheet is hyperlinked in the *Gantt spreadsheet* in the "Name of the project" cell.

3) This project spreadsheet is based on a *Template* that I have in my Drive. (Therefore, each time I have a new project, I copy this *Template* and then rename it with the name of the project).

---

#### **2 challenges:**

• Would it be possible to **automatically generate a new spreadsheet and rename it** with the name of the "Name of the project" cell (in the *Gantt spreadsheet*)?

Would it even be possible to generate this new project spreadsheet based on the *Template*?

(It would require a script like: "Get the text of the cell" > "Copy the *Template* spreadsheet" > "Rename it with the name of the cell" > "Open the *Newly created spreadsheet*" > "Get the URL of the *Newly created spreadsheet*" > "Hyperlink the corresponding "Name of the project" cell with this URL".)

• (A bit more complicated) Would it be possible to **auto-complete the *Newly created spreadsheet*** with the information completed in the *Gantt spreadsheet* (person in charge, email, beginning and due date) by copy-pasting the corresponding cells of the project?

(For instance: "Copy the name of the person in charge of the project from the Gantt spreadsheet (maybe with a `VLOOKUP(Project;A2:G2;2;FALSE)`, I don't know...) and paste it in the *Newly created spreadsheet* in the cell B3." (And same with the other cells to be copied.))

I can send you the links of the sheets if needed to give you more view on it.

**______________________________________________**

Here-under a snapshot of the *Gantt spreadsheet*

[image: Gantt spreadsheet]

Here-under a snapshot the *Template* spreadsheet (with the cells to be auto-completed).

[image: Template spreadsheet]

Comment: To start learning about Google Apps Script go to [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)

Comment: To make external references in Google Sheets, use [IMPORTRANGE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be looking in the direction of using a single form to more or less accomplish both tasks. In other words use the form to populate both the Gantt chart AND the new project sheet.